# Slope of tangent when $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\leq(x_1-x_2)^2$ for all $x_1,x_2 \in R$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\leq(x_1-x_2)^2$ for all $x_1,x_2 \in R$, then find the slope of tangent to the curve at $y=f(x)$ at the point $(1,2)$.

Could someone hint me as how to approach this question. Is data sufficient to find the required slope?

Comment: Can you spot the definition of derivative on that inequality (except for it lacking the limit sign)?

Answer (score -3):

[image]

I hope this helps. Next time, learn your definitions